# Codeigniter time showing as AM not PM

Tags: codeigniter, time, controller, timestamp, helper

I am using the codeigniter time helper to echo the TIMESTAMP (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) row of my mysql database.

The timestamp in my database in raw format is: `2011-11-15 14:40:45`

When I echo the time in my view using the helper i get the following: `15/11/2011 02:40`

My time now appears to be in AM. Why???

This is the code I use to echo the time:

```
$the_date = mdate('%d/%m/%Y %h:%i', strtotime($row->date))

echo $the_date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the format of your data when returning it from the database. Chage the lowercase h (%h) to a capital H (%H) to return 24-hour format rather than the 12 hour you're currently getting.

You're code should look like the below:

```
$the_date = mdate('%d/%m/%Y %H:%i', strtotime($row->date))
```